# Bad looking linear-gradient in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, linear-gradients

I just noticed a strange rendering issue with the `linear-gradient` in the latest Firefox: it looks like it renders background gradient with bars of solid colors with straight borders between them (see picture below). In Chrome the same gradient looks smooth.

Is it known and how to avoid it?

- **Code example:** https://codepen.io/pavsad/pen/YzXvwEp
- **Firefox version:** 74.0 (64-bit) (also tested in 72.0 & 69.0)
- **Device:** iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, 2017) (Radeon PRO 580) MacOS Mojave 10.14.6

Code example:

```css
background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 255, 1));
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like the issue disappears if i change opacity to 100% (without transparency)

Comment: Just found something similar at bugzilla https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1621202

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an issue in the FF bugzilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1623337

From the discussion it seems the issue relates due to using of two colors in gradient with **different** values for **alpha** channel.

At the moment of writing there are no news on fixing that.